# redirecting output of command to variable

Tags: bash

Easyly:

```
export a=$(avconv -i "first.mp3")
```

or

```
export a=`avconv -i first.mp3`
```

output of avconv goes to stdout and does not to variable a

Comment: Why do you think the output of avconv does not go to stdout? By default avconv logs to stderr as the manual tells you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
a="$(avconv -i first.mp3 2>&1)"
```